# Vue.js persistent remote storage using Rest Api

Tags: jquery, rest, vue.js, vue-resource

In the example [TodoMVC](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/todomvc.html), I understand I can hook into the `fetch` and  `save` function to use jQuery Ajax Get/Post to interact with backend APIs for remote storage.

e.g.

```
var todoStorage = {
  fetch: function () {
    var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) || '[]')
    todos.forEach(function (todo, index) {
      todo.id = index
    })
    todoStorage.uid = todos.length
    return todos
  },
  save: function (todos) {
    localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos))
  }
}
```

But since my backend is already restful API, are there any more elegant way to map my Restful Apis more neatly?

Answer (score -1):

Yes.
You can use any AJAX library, like Vue-resource and use:
`Vue.$http.post` to save data and `Vue.$http.get` to get data.
Simple like that.